# How to update PyQt progressbar from an independent function with arguments?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to use multiple imported function with arguments that takes some while to run. I want a 'working' progress bar that track the processes of that function. I have followed 2 questions already here.

1. [Connect an imported function to Qt5 progress bar without dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57323237/connect-an-imported-function-to-qt5-progress-bar-without-dependencies)
2. [Report progress to QProgressBar using variable from an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40140531/report-progress-to-qprogressbar-using-variable-from-an-imported-module)

The difference is that the thread can take any function which can have arguments. The function also not needs to `yield` the percent to return to the progressbar. The progressbar always start at 0%.

I copied a snippet from first link and modified it for example purpose.

```
from external_script import long_running_function

class Actions(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.show()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        long_running_function(**kwargs) # This can be any function that takes argument/s
        self.progress.setValue(value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not get too complicated with the answers as they are limited to a very particular context. In general the logic is to pass a QObject to it that updates the percentage value and then emits a signal with that value. For example a simple solution is to use the threading module:

```py
import sys
import threading

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class PercentageWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    percentageChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._percentage = 0

    @property
    def percentage(self):
        return self._percentage

    @percentage.setter
    def percentage(self, value):
        if self._percentage == value:
            return
        self._percentage = value
        self.percentageChanged.emit(self.percentage)

    def start(self):
        self.started.emit()

    def finish(self):
        self.finished.emit()


class FakeWorker:
    def start(self):
        pass

    def finish(self):
        pass

    @property
    def percentage(self):
        return 0

    @percentage.setter
    def percentage(self, value):
        pass


import time


def long_running_function(foo, baz="1", worker=None):
    if worker is None:
        worker = FakeWorker()
    worker.start()
    while worker.percentage < 100:
        worker.percentage += 1
        print(foo, baz)
        time.sleep(1)
        worker.finish()


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.progress = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Start")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.button)
        lay.addWidget(self.progress)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.launch)

    def launch(self):
        worker = PercentageWorker()
        worker.percentageChanged.connect(self.progress.setValue)
        threading.Thread(
            target=long_running_function,
            args=("foo",),
            kwargs=dict(baz="baz", worker=worker),
            daemon=True,
        ).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I still do not get it. Should the imported function be dependent on `FakeWorker()`? The imported function must not be modified at all.

Comment: @Nikko You should put that in your post because if you analyze the links you provide then you will see that the imported function is always modified